# Sphinx search on Ubuntu behaves weird

Tags: sphinx, ubuntu-10.04

I'm having some issues with Sphinx Search on Ubuntu. My test setup is on a Mac, I use the precompiled binary from sphinxsearch.com.

When testing exceptions everything is fine. E.g. I want to map "starwars" to "star wars", so I have `starwars => star wars` in my exceptions.txt, works great. When I do the same on our Ubuntu server, if does nothing.

I've tried compiling sphinx myself, still no luck. What's going on, and does anyone else see this difference between operating systems?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 lts and the lasted Sphinx Search (64bit).

Comment: Are versions on Mac and Ubuntu same?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the output of indexer - it may well reveal some issue reading the exceptions file.

Perhaps the permissions arent setup to allow indexer AND searchd to read the file?

Or the path is wrong. Its the simply things that usually cause this

Or could be that you simply didnt reindex and restart searchd after setting up the exceptions?